# Evaluate $\int_{-1}^{3}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\pi }}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\pi-y^2}} \sin(x^2 + y^2 ) \,dxdydz$

Tags: definite-integrals, power-series, taylor-expansion

> Evaluate $$\int_{-1}^{3}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\pi }}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\pi-y^2}}  \sin(x^2 + y^2 )  \,dxdydz$$

I am stuck trying to express the  sine  as series. What is the best move?

Comment: Did you try using spherical coordinates?

Comment: It this 
$\int_{-1}^3 dx \int_0^{\surd \pi}dy \int_0^{\sqrt{\pi-y^2}}dz sin... $
or
$\int_{-1}^3 dy \int_0^{\surd \pi}dx \int_0^{\sqrt{\pi-y^2}}dz sin... $
or
$\int_{-1}^3 dy \int_0^{\surd \pi}dz \int_0^{\sqrt{\pi-y^2}}dx sin... $
or
$\int_{-1}^3 dz \int_0^{\surd \pi}dy \int_0^{\sqrt{\pi-y^2}}dx sin... $
?

Answer (score 0):

What about cylindrical coordinates?:

$$0\le r\le \sqrt\pi\;,\;\;0\le\theta\le\frac\pi2\;,\;\;-1\le z\le 3$$

So your integral becomes

$$\frac1\pi\int_0^{\sqrt\pi}dr\int_0^{\pi/2}d\theta\int_{-1}^3 r\,\sin r^2\,dz =2$$